# Script to control network balancing on Mac

Tags: macos, scripting, network-programming, download, nlb

I was wondering if there is any script that will allow one to limit the network bandwidth (download\upload) for a certain process on a mac?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [waterroof](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/) to accomplish that.
It is a front-end for ipfw and provides a tool named "connection inspector" which can monitor each network connection and throttle its bandwidth, in theory, but I had no chance to test it so far. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Yosemite no longer includes IPFW, you can use PF instead of it,  [here is a script](https://github.com/MrBoog/Limiting-bandwidth-on-MacOS/blob/master/pf.sh)